# Creating a dynamic column on grouped mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in mysql

```
msg_id | thread_id | read_status
--------------------------------
1      | 1         | read
2      | 1         | read
3      | 2         | unread
4      | 2         | read
5      | 2         | read
6      | 3         | read
7      | 3         | unread
```

I want a query that will show me all messages grouped by thread_id and if they contain any unread messages I want the a column called read_status to show unread

so the query result would look like this:

```
thread_id | read_status
-----------------------
1         | read
2         | unread
3         | unread
```

So far i have:

```
SELECT 
thread_id,
IF(user_read_status = 'U',"unread","read") as message_status FROM messages
GROUP BY thread_id
```

but this populates the "read_status" with the result of whatever the first message is, rather than if any of the messages are unread...

I have no idea about how to do this, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: read http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need aggregation, such as:

```
select thread_id, 
       (case when sum(user_read_status = 'U') > 0 then 'unread' else 'read' end) as thread_status
from messages
group by thread_id;
```

If the message statuses are really "read" and "unread" (as in the sample data), you can take this shortcut:

```
select thread_id, max(message_status) as thread_status
from messages
group by thread_id;
```

This only works because you have two statuses and the alphabetical ordering has a meaning.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, in reality my table has "U" and "R" as the 2 values so option 2 works perfectly, but nice to know about option 1 for future reference. Thanks again